# Derivative of the error function with respect to the parameters in the linear regression model

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Given the following setting for a linear regression model, the error function's derivative w.r.t the parameters $\theta$ is computed as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l@{}l}
\mathcal{\frac{dL}{d\theta}} 
    &{}= \frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y-X\theta)^T(y-X\theta)) \\
    &{}= \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\frac{d}{d\theta}(y^Ty-2y^TX\theta+\theta^TX^TX\theta) \\
    &{}= \frac{1}{\sigma^2}(-y^TX+\theta^TX^TX) \in R^{1 \times D}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Where $X \in R^{N \times D}$, $y \in R^{N \times 1}$

I cannot understand why we obtain the term $2y^TX\theta$ in the second step starting form the first step.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain rule asserts $(f(g(x)))’=f’(g(x))g’(x)$. Note the loss function is the composition of $f:x\mapsto x^Tx$ and $g:x\mapsto y-Xx$. We have $f’(x) = 2x^T$ and $g’(x)=-X$. Whence the derivative of the loss function is $-2(y-X\theta)^TX$.

Background on derivatives: Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$. Then $f$ is said to be differentiable at $x$ if there is a matrix $T$ such that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Th\| }{\|h\|}=0$$ (Note the ambiguity in the norm. This is okay because all norms in finite dimensional space are equivalent.) It is easy to show this linear map, if it exists, is unique. Thus we denote it $f’(x)$. It is also easy to show that $f’(x)$ is the matrix with entry $(f’)_{ij}=D_jf_i$, that is, the partial derivative of $f_i$ with respect to the $j$th entry of its input. (Warning: The matrix of partials can exist, and yet $f$ is not differentiable.)

Finally, a word on convention. In the special case of $f$ is a scalar field, $f’$ is a row vector. The gradient $\nabla f$ is a column vector. However, this distinction is often not observed, which can lead to confusion.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the derivative of $x^Tx$ is $2x^T$? That's what I was missing. It could be really helpful if you could point me to a link where I can rehearse these rules and their derivations. Thanks!

Comment: Put $f(x)=x^Tx = x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2$. Then $\partial f/\partial x_i = 2x_i$, which yields $f’(x)=2x^T$.